# Getting "internal server error" on passing binary data to AWS Lambda function deployed using serverless framework and apigw-binary plugin

Tags: aws-lambda, binary, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

#### what I'm trying

Passing binary data via Lambda integration in API gateway. Lambda returns back text.

#### issue

The function returns desired output when API gateway is configured from console. To implement it using serverless framework I installed **serverless-apigw-binary** plugin. The required binary types show up in API gateway>settings>binary media types. However on calling API I get "internal server error". The function works properly on application/json type input. After enabling-disabling lambda proxy integration and adding mappings via console, I get correct output.

#### serverless.yml file

```
org: ------
app: ---------
service: ---------
frameworkVersion: ">=1.34.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-apigw-binary
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7 #fixed with pipenv
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 60
  profile: ----

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    usePipenv: true
    useDownloadCache: true
    useStaticCache: true
  apigwBinary:
    types:           #list of mime-types
      - 'application/octet-stream'
      - 'application/zip'


functions:
  main:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: ocr
          method: post
          integration: lambda
          request:
            passThrough: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
            template:
              application/zip: '
              {
                  "type": "zip",
                  "zip": "$input.body",
                  "lang": "$input.params(''lang'')",
                  "config": "$input.params(''config'')",
                  "output_type": "$input.params(''output_type'')"
              }'
              application/json: '
              {
                  "type": "json",
                  "image": $input.json(''$.image''),
                  "lang": "$input.params(''lang'')",
                  "config": "$input.params(''config'')",
                  "output_type": "$input.params(''output_type'')"
              }'
              application/octet-stream: '
              {
                  "type": "img_file",
                  "image": "$input.body",
                  "lang": "$input.params(''lang'')",
                  "config": "$input.params(''config'')",
                  "output_type": "$input.params(''output_type'')"
              }'
```

#### handler.py

```py
def main(event, context):
    # do something on event and get txt
    return txt
```

#### edit

I compared swagger definitions and found this
1. API generated from console(working)

```
paths:
  /ocr:
    post:
      consumes:
      - "application/octet-stream"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
```

2. API generated from serverless framework

```
paths:
  /ocr:
    post:
      consumes:
      - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      - "application/zip"
      - "application/octet-stream"
      - "application/json"
      responses:
```

**produces: - "application/json"** is missing. How do I add it in serverless?